# Discord.js Reactions to prior messages are not triggered

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently facing a weird issue with discord.js

Basically I will recieve the reaction object whenever its trigger

However only if the message that has been reacted to has been created after the bot has been started

If I start my bot and react to a prior message the reaction will not be recieved

this is my code

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
     console.log(reaction)
})
```

Comment: You should use partials as I mentioned in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add partials to your client like so:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: 32767, // all intents
    partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENT', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER'] // all partials
})
```

You may not want/need them all so this is just for example.